# How to copy files using Wix Bootstrapper

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have this very specific scenario where I need to install already existing MSI (that I don't have sources to) and copy some additional dlls to the destination folder. I created Wix Bootstrapper, that will launch MSI, however, it seems like I can only use EXE or MSI as a child of Chain:

```
<Bundle>
  <Chain>
    <MsiPackage SourceFile="MyAwesomeInstaller.msi" />
  </Chain>
</Bundle>
```

Is it possible to just copy files as part of the Chain? I tried using

```
<Payload SourceFile="FileThatNeedsToGoToInstallFolder.dll" Id="MyAwesomeFile"/>
```

But that will not copy the file to the final destination.

Thanks!

Comment: You can add your own MSI with your files to the chain and launch it in silent mode, so user wont see it separately.

Comment: @Mischo5500 that's what I end up doing, however I didn't like the solution, I would prefer to have something as part of the chain

Answer (score 0):

One workaround would be to add an `ExePackage` that runs a batch script to copy the files. Likes this:

```
<ExePackage Id="MyId" DisplayName="Copying additional files for xx.msi" SourceFile="mybatchfile.cmd" Permanent="yes">
   <Payload Id="myDll" SourceFile="mydll.dll"/>
</ExePackage>
```

Might not be pretty but it is something.